# Asymptote: have stuff outside the box

Tags: asymptote

I'm using Asymptote to draw my graphics.  I am making a graph of arctan.  I want to label the graph, but I want the label to poke outside the bounding box.   I want this because if I just let Asymptote include the label in the bounding box then when I put the figure in the document and center it, then it looks off-center (would the right term be that the label doesn't have graphic "weight"?).

Briefly, if change what's below to say `\makebox[0em][l]{$\arctan(..)$}` then Asymptote clips the text at the bounding box.  How do I preserve the bb, but have all of the label appear?

```
// arctan.asy
import settings;
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render=0;

unitsize(1cm);

import graph;
real f(real x) {
  return (atan(x)+(pi/2.0))/pi;
}

real xmin = -3.5;
real xmax = 3.5;
real ymin = -0.35;
real ymax = 1.5;

draw((xmin,0) -- (xmax,0), blue, arrow=None);
draw((0,ymin) -- (0,ymax), blue, arrow = None);

path g = graph(f,xmin,xmax);
draw(g,red);
label("\makebox[0em][c]{$\scriptstyle (\arctan(x)+(\pi/2))/\pi$}", (2.15,0.8), S);
```

Obviously I can do this one with some fudging by eye.  But is there an automatic soution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably an easier way, but here is a solution.  The `centerAtOrigin` function shown in the code below will fill a transparent rectangle over the plot.  The rectangle is scaled and centered on the origin such that the graph origin is left-right centered.  I've added the black border in the plot below just to illustrate the white border to the left of the plot.

```
// arctan.asy
import settings;
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render=0;

unitsize(1cm);

import graph;
real f(real x) {
  return (atan(x)+(pi/2.0))/pi;
}

real xmin = -3.5;
real xmax = 3.5;
real ymin = -0.35;
real ymax = 1.5;

draw((xmin,0) -- (xmax,0), blue, arrow=None);
draw((0,ymin) -- (0,ymax), blue, arrow = None);

path g = graph(f,xmin,xmax);
draw(g,red);
label("$\scriptstyle (\arctan(x)+(\pi/2))/\pi$", (xmax,0.8), S);

void centerAtOrigin()
{
    pair origMinPoint = min(currentpicture)/72*2.54;
    pair origMaxPoint = max(currentpicture)/72*2.54;
    pair origSize = size(currentpicture)/72*2.54;
    real xmin = origMinPoint.x;
    real xmax = origMaxPoint.x;
    real ymin = origMinPoint.y;
    if (xmax > fabs(xmin)) { xmin = -xmax; }
    if (fabs(xmin) > xmax) { xmax = -xmin; }
    fill(shift(xmin,ymin)*scale(xmax-xmin,origSize.y)*
        unitsquare, opacity(0)+white);
}

centerAtOrigin();
```

[image]

**Edit:** Instead of showing the label even though it's outside of the bounding box, this method expands the bounding box on the other side to keep your vertical axis centered.